# Unable to get Access Token in Android App which uses facebook api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need help regarding accessToken of the facebook, the problem here is when i try to call accessToken method it returns a null. Actually i want to post comments from my app to the specific page and get comments from the page-id where these posts are posted.

The problem i have got is when i try to post comment i get an error like this *An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.*

and when i tried to get comments i get this error *An access token is required to request this resource*

I need help as i got stuck here.

Thanks for the help!!

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);

    editText = (EditText) linearLayout2.findViewById(R.id.commentBox);
    button = (Button) linearLayout2.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

    openfeed = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.findViewById(R.id.fakebutton);

    initInstances();
    initCallbackManager();
    refreshButtonState();
    getAllComments();


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("message", editText.getText().toString());
            GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(
                    accessToken,
                    "/me/feed",
                    params,
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            System.out.println("Success: " + response);
                        }
                    }
            );
            graphRequest.executeAsync();
        }
    });
    return linearLayout2;
}

private void initInstances() {
    System.out.println("I am init");
    openfeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("publish_actions,publish_pages,manage_pages,user_about_me"));
        }
    });
}


private void initCallbackManager() {
    System.out.println("i am initCallbackManager");
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            refreshButtonState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });

}

private void refreshButtonState() {
    System.out.println("refresh button state");
    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        openfeed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        openfeed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private boolean isLoggedIn() {

    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    return  accessToken != null;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void getAllComments() {
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/{page-id}/feed",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    System.out.println("comments: " + response);
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the error? Can you post the LogCat?

Comment: @Skizo For getting comments this i get as response *{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 104, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An access token is required to request this resource.}}* and for 
post *{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}}*

Comment: Try this on the latest FB SDK and with one of the bundled projects. If it works, then study these samples and see what's your missing